# How to disable remaining panorama sections disable when we are in one panorma section

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing Windows Phone 8 application using Panorama. I have added 4 Panorama items. When I am in first section, we can see the immediate next section. right? At this point, I am able to click on buttons of that immediate panorama section. Now I want to disable that Panorama section. It has to be activated whenever I would be navigated to that section.

How to accomplish this task in Windows phone 8 development? Do we need to write any special code behind or can we handle it in xaml?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use **Loaded event handler** for panorama items and have all content of items disabled in all panorama items by default. Now just enable respective controls of a panorama item when its being loaded (in Loaded event handler). Also disable all controls of this panoramic item when it unload.
You need to trigger Loaded event handler for all panorama items.

Hope this help you.

Zauk